# Sorting XPath expressions into document order

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I need to evaluate multiple XPath expressions against a document.  The documents are large, so we're using a streaming parser.  The XPath expressions simply return the value of a node.  I need to order the XPath expressions so that they are in document order (since once I evaluate an expression, evaluation of the next expression begins at the point in the document where the last value was found).  I have the schema for the document, but I'm unsure how to use it to establish the order.

I'm using C# with .NET 4, if that matters.  If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it!

FOLLOWUP: As Dimitre noted, this is not possible with full XPath.  Restricting expressions to the [XML Signature Streaming Profile](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-xmldsig-xpath-20110421/), I was able to construct a tree, with each node containing the element name and an ordinal position (the order in which it appeared within the schema).  Once I had the tree built, I then traversed it with the XPath, collecting the positions in a list.  Once I had the list of positions, it was easy to compare the lists and determine the relative positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not achievable without posing some limitations on the XPath expressions**.

**For example**, any XPath expression that contains the axes `descendant::`, `descendant-or-self::`, `ancestor::`, `ancestor-or-self::`, `preceding::`, `following::` and even the axes `preceding-sibling::` and `following-sibling::` -- may require reading the XML document completely.

**In case the XPath expressions don't contain these axes**, you could arrange them by the number of location steps (they also shouldn't contain `parent::` or `..`), and you can **temporarily** stop evaluating any expression with number of location paths smaller than the current depth.